# When checking for the details, Software Updater always shows: "no network detected", any way to fix this?

Tags: networking, upgrade

In the old days, when I clicked on an item in the list of packages to be upgraded by the **Software Upgrader** interface, I would see details about the package and some information for why this upgrade should happen (I suppose from the `changelog` file).

It has been a while since that feature broken (for me) on my host machine or any VM in any version of Ubuntu (at least with 18.04, 20.04, 22.04, most certainly the intermediate versions would have a similar issue). I use VirtualBox for my VMs.

I'm wondering whether others have similar issues and a way to fix the issue. I have a strong firewall, but nothing that would block a software to go out and gather such information...

The upgrade works just fine (i.e. the *"No network connection detected"* message is a quite a lie, I'm connected now to post this message...)

One more detail: I setup the network manually in all cases. Especially, I assign a fixed IP to each computer (Host & VMs) by editing the netplan. I do not try to use the Network Manager.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.123/24
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      optional: false
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 75.75.75.75
          - 75.75.76.76
```

[image]

Comment: It is working for me in a 20.04 VM running on virtualbox. When I have "technical description" open and click the package name, I get a momentary "Downloading list of changes" displayed and a Cancel button, but then it comes up with the information. You can do the same thing in `aptitude` by selecting the package to be updated and pressing C, does that work on your system?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes. It works in `aptitude`. I suppose in that case it just tries to load the data (opposed to the "Software Manager" which may first check for a network connection and fails). Also I made an update showing how the network is setup on a VM.